# por que estoy mal? es un convertidor de dolares a soles peruanos pesos mexicanos y chilenos

Tags: javascript

```
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars=50) {
  var arr = [peruvianSoles, mexicanPesos, chileanPesos];
  var peruvianSoles = (usDollars.prompt(usDollars*3.25));
  var mexicanPesos = (usDollars.prompt(usDollars*18));
  var chileanPesos = (usDollars.prompt(usDollars*660))/* tu código aquí */;

  // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(console.log( peruvianSoles.length) + " soles peruanos" );

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(console.log( mexicanPesos.length) + " pesos mexicanos");

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(console.log(chileanPesos.length) + " pesos chilenos");

  return arr;
};
```

Comment: puedes explicar que falla, cual es el error, a proposito te invito a hacer el [tour]

Comment: Hola, ¿de dónde sale `prompt`?

Answer (score 0):

No, entiendo muy bien que estabas haciendo, supongo que la funcion recibe la cantidad de dolares a convertir, prueba de esta forma

```
function coinConvert(usDollars=50) {
  var peruvianSoles = usDollars*3.25;
  var mexicanPesos = usDollars*18;
  var chileanPesos = usDollars*660;

  var arr = {
     peruvianSoles: peruvianSoles + " soles peruanos",
     mexicanPesos: mexicanPesos + " pesos mexicanos",
     chileanPesos: chileanPesos + " pesos chilenos"
  };

  console.log(arr);

  return arr;
};

function coinConvert(usDollars=50) {
  var arr = [];

  var peruvianSoles = usDollars*3.25;
  var mexicanPesos = usDollars*18;
  var chileanPesos = usDollars*660;

  arr.push(peruvianSoles + " soles peruanos");
  arr.push(mexicanPesos + " pesos mexicanos");
  arr.push(chileanPesos + " pesos chilenos");

  console.log(arr);

  return arr;
};
```

Comment: se agradece tu apoyo, pero lo ideal sería esperar a que el OP aclare cual es el fallo y el comportamiento exacto de su software

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Que es OP?

Comment: Original Poster, o en pocas palabras el autor de la pregunta

Comment: y en caso de que quiera agregar un arr.push por cada tipo de divisa, que codigo seria?

Comment: puedes hacer un arr.push, pero perderías los indices, el método push te añade al final del arreglo, no en un indice específico, o sea tendrías q tener claro en cada posición del arreglo el valor de q tienes, de todas maneras te lo actualizo con el push